# How do I render an SVG in an Android app?

Tags: android, svg

After finding [Display SVG Image in image view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871286/display-svg-image-in-image-view-in-android) on Google and going to [Having issue on Real Device using vector image in android. SVG-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356098/having-issue-on-real-device-using-vector-image-in-android-svg-android), I find that "You need a 3rd-party JAR to do it" is a bit of overkill. **Is there any way to render an SVG without using 3rd-party libraries?**

Answer (score 3):

I managed to display an SVG using a `WebView`, since that is more than capable of rendering an SVG:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/file.svg"); // point it to the SVG
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); // set the background to transparent
```

This makes it render much like a transparent PNG would in an `ImageView`. The only caveat is that the SVG *must* use the `viewBox` attribute and *not* use the `height` or `width` attributes, to ensure it resizes properly.

Comment: Note that this will only work on Android 3.0+, as [there was no SVG support in `WebView` prior to that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677397/svg-support-in-android).

Comment: @CommonsWare good eye! Gladly, that should cover 84.3% of devices as of today, according to Android Studio. Perhaps a small webpage with some script could be used here to detect if support exists and, if not, fall back to a PNG with `max-width` and `max-height` set to `100%`.

Comment: It would be simpler just use to use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and only use your `loadUrl()` approach on a supported version, falling back to something else in the Java layer, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Using [custom fonts](http://chiuki.github.io/beautiful-android/#37) actually works really well in Android.

You can use the free [icomoon](http://icomoon.io/) web application to convert SVGs to custom `.ttf` font characters.

Comment: That'd work great for single-color images, but what about ones like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Hawaii_Island_topographic_map_CSS3_animation.svg ?

Comment: Wow, that's not what I expected. Is the original a Digital Elevation Model file? If the webview works for you, definitely use that. If it doesn't, I'd try converting it to .obj (simplifying the model as much as I could get away with) and use an OpenGL library like min3D or Rajawali to render it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=min3d.sampleProject1

Comment: lol well that seems a bit much, but it might work. Thanks for offering alternatives!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for imagePicker sort of feature then,

```
webView.loadURl(selectedFileLocation.toString)
```

else if it is to display a .svg image from web,

```
webView.loadURl(/*url for the .svg file*/)
```